# Force.com Source Scanner Results: FLS Update and Create

Tags: apex, managed-package, security-review, fls, source-scanner

I've run the `Force.com Source Scanner` against my `Managed Package` and here are the summary results:

[image]

There are two areas `FLS Update` and `FLS Create` where I got 28, and 37 risks respectively...

I am wondering, do I have to put in code checks for each risk, or is it OK to add these as `False Positives`document because the `Permission Set` included in the package is applied to all users to who this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need the FLS checks. The reason why is that administrators could choose to create a new Permission Set and allow users access to the code but not the fields for whatever reason, or even edit profiles and add code access directly, without field/object access. Never assume that your subscribers won't accidentally (or even intentionally) create security concerns by creating odd security setups.